# No hubs have been subscribed to. (SIGNALR Cross Domain)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to connect SIGNALR hub from my different application (CROSS DOMAIN).

It's connected but the above error is coming in SIGNALR logging.

This is my client application code

```
 <script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.chattingHub;
        $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:2372/signalr';
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        });

    });
</script>
```

This is my Sever side application code which connected and works withing the same application.

```
  <script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.chattingHub;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        hub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log($.connection.hub);
            $('#sendMessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                hub.server.sendMessage($('#username').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });

        });

        //signalr method for push server message to client
       /* hub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            console.log(name, message);
        };*/
    });
</script>
```

On server application I enabled cross origin also and it's connecting but on client side hub is not subscribed.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to enable `jsonp`;

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HubConfiguration();
    config.EnableJSONP = true;
    app.MapSignalR(config);                       
}
```

Then create the connection by `jsonp:true` parameter;

```
var hub = $.connection.chattingHub;
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:2372/signalr';
$.connection.hub.logging = true;

$.connection.hub.start({jsonp:true}).done(function () {

});
```